output value as timevalue - I think
I have this working code I'm using for lap times for races, or I wanna use.
Right now I can fill out a list for players and their lap times using Rows-count - it works great, and then I use If-error Index comparison to make the top5 list. but the if-error index only works if my lap times come out looking like this inside the cells mm:ss,mss (12:34,567) but in the formula bar they look like hh:mm:ss I thin 00:12:34 and this works great If I'm the one punching in the numbers via keyboard and adding the colons manual, but with help I'm gotten this code put together to add the colons automatically. But when this code put in the colons, the format is the same inside the cell and the formulabar, and then my if-error index does not work to create my top5 list..
heres my little code that does not output the numbers correctly
 If Target.Address = "$D$4" Then
        Dim UserInput1
        UserInput1 = Target.Value
        If UserInput1 > 1 Then
        NewInput = Left(UserInput1, 2) & ":" & Mid(UserInput1, 3, 2) & "," & Mid(UserInput1, 5, 3)
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Target = NewInput
        Application.EnableEvents = True
        End If
    End If

I have tried google to find and use time format, to change the NewInput to a timevalue, because I think that's what's needed.. but I'm not sure. But I've tried and failed for many hours.
So now I'm here once again, asking for help
And just playing with my code again I just realised that I can't put in single minutes.. As in "02:34,123" my code just removes the zero and makes it "23:41,23" so apparently my code is very flawed -  HEEEELP

Target = Cdbl(NewInput) and Target.NumberFormat = "hh:mm:ss.000"

replacing the Target = NewInput with Target = Cdbl(NewInput) Target.NumberFormat = "hh:mm:ss.000" just returns the new value as 00:00,000 but just playing with my code again I just realised that I can't put in single minutes as in 02:34,123 my code just removes the zero and makes it 23:41,23 so apparently my code is very flawed

I assumed this was a worksheet change event this was in
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Address = "$D$4" Then

    Dim vSplitTheValueUpOnDelimiter As Variant
    vSplitTheValueUpOnDelimiter = Split(Target.Value, ":")
    
    'Check how many times there were a delmiter of ":"
    If UBound(vSplitTheValueUpOnDelimiter) = 2 Then
        Target.Value = CStr(vSplitTheValueUpOnDelimiter(0) & ":" & vSplitTheValueUpOnDelimiter(1) & "," & vSplitTheValueUpOnDelimiter(2))
        
        'If you are still loosing 0's un comment this line and comment the line above
        'Target.Value = "'" & CStr(vSplitTheValueUpOnDelimiter(0) & ":" & vSplitTheValueUpOnDelimiter(1) & "," & vSplitTheValueUpOnDelimiter(2))
        
    End If
End If
End Sub

I also didn't know what the $D$4 absolute position was about but didn't care to ask to many questions, because I had a lot
I also tried to keep the code simple so it I don't feel the need to explain why I did what I did.
Also please mark my response as the answer if it worked for you

A Worksheet Change: Enter Time As Digits Only To End Up With Formatted Value

Sheet Module e.g. Sheet1
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Const TARGET_FIRST_CELL_ADDRESS As String = "D4"
    Const NOT_ALL_DIGITS_PREFIX As String = "Not All Digits: "
    Const IS_ERROR_PREFIX As String = "Is an Error: "
    Const IS_DATE_PREFIX As String = "Is a Date: "
    Const IS_BOOLEAN_PREFIX As String = "Is a Boolean: "
    Const INVALID_SECONDS_PREFIX As String = "Invalid Seconds: "
    Const INVALID_MINUTES_PREFIX As String = "Invalid Minutes: "
    Const TIME_FORMAT As String = "[h]:mm:ss.000"
    Const APPLY_COLUMN_TIME_FORMAT As Boolean = False
    
    Dim trg As Range, rCount As Long
    
    With Me.Range(TARGET_FIRST_CELL_ADDRESS)
        rCount = Me.Cells(Me.Rows.Count, .Column).End(xlUp).Row - .Row + 1
        If rCount < 1 Then Exit Sub
        Set trg = .Resize(rCount)
    End With
    
    Dim irg As Range: Set irg = Intersect(trg, Target)
    If irg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    If APPLY_COLUMN_TIME_FORMAT Then trg.NumberFormat = TIME_FORMAT
    
    Dim icell As Range, CellValue As Variant, Result As Variant
    Dim i As Long, n As Long, sNum As Double, mNum As Long, hNum As Long
    Dim CellString As String, BuiltString As String
    Dim StringLength As Long, HasNoResult As Boolean
    Dim AreSecondsInvalid As Boolean, AreMinutesInvalid As Boolean
    
    For Each icell In irg.Cells
        
        CellValue = icell.Value2
        
        If IsError(CellValue) Then ' error
            Result = IS_ERROR_PREFIX & icell.Text
        ElseIf VarType(CellValue) = vbBoolean Then ' TRUE, FALSE
            Result = IS_BOOLEAN_PREFIX & UCase(CellValue)
        ' Works only when appropriate format.
        ElseIf IsDate(CellValue) Then ' date
            Result = IS_DATE_PREFIX & CStr(CellValue)
        ' Add more!?
        Else
            HasNoResult = True
            CellString = CStr(icell.Value)
            StringLength = Len(CellString)
        End If
            
        If HasNoResult Then
            
            If StringLength > 0 Then
                
                If CellString Like String(StringLength, "#") Then
                    
                    For i = Len(CellString) To 1 Step -1
                        n = n + 1
                        BuiltString = Mid(CellString, i, 1) & BuiltString
                        Select Case n
                            Case 3: BuiltString = "." & BuiltString: n = n + 1
                            Case 6:
                                If Val(Left(BuiltString, 1)) > 5 Then
                                    AreSecondsInvalid = True
                                Else
                                    sNum = Val(BuiltString)
                                    BuiltString = vbNullString
                                End If
                            Case 8:
                                If Val(Left(BuiltString, 1)) > 5 Then
                                    AreMinutesInvalid = True
                                Else
                                    mNum = Val(BuiltString)
                                    BuiltString = vbNullString
                                End If
                            Case Else ' continue building; do nothing
                        End Select
                    Next i
                    
                    If AreSecondsInvalid Then
                        Result = INVALID_SECONDS_PREFIX & CellString
                        AreSecondsInvalid = False ' reset
                    ElseIf AreMinutesInvalid Then
                        Result = INVALID_MINUTES_PREFIX & CellString
                        AreMinutesInvalid = False ' reset
                    Else
                        Select Case n
                            Case Is < 6
                                sNum = Val(Left("00.000", 6 - n) & BuiltString)
                            Case 7
                                mNum = Val(BuiltString)
                            Case Is > 8
                                hNum = Val(BuiltString)
                        End Select
                        Result = hNum / 24 + mNum / 1440 + sNum / 86400
                    End If
                    
                    ' Reset.
                    hNum = 0
                    mNum = 0
                    sNum = 0
                    BuiltString = vbNullString
                    n = 0
                    
                Else ' not all digits
                    
                    Result = NOT_ALL_DIGITS_PREFIX & CellString
                
                End If
            
                HasNoResult = False
                    
            'Else ' empty; StringLength = 0
            End If
        
        'Else ' HasNoResult = False
        End If
    
        ' Write to cell.
        If HasNoResult Then
            HasNoResult = False ' reset
        Else
            Application.EnableEvents = False
                icell.Value = Result
            Application.EnableEvents = True
            Result = Empty
        End If
    
    Next icell

End Sub

